# Turning laptop into a server to run spring tool suite over the internet

Tags: spring, web, web-deployment, spring-tool-suite, catalina

I am trying to run a website from my computer using Spring Tool Suite (STS). Using pivotal tc Server I can access this website that I made by running the server and using localhost:8080 as a url.

My laptop contains other software that is permitted to only run in the laptop and it is needed to run my code in Spring tool suite.(School policy to SSH's into another computer to get access to my database; it is a requirement)

How would I be able to access that website that is running in my laptop that uses pivotal tc Server.  Please assume I know nothing about IP address and DNS. Also, assume that I can move my laptop around like a mobile device.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly. You would like to run tc Server on your laptop from within STS and you would like to access that webapp not only from the machine itself (via localhost:8080), but also from anywhere else in the world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to tunnel to your local machine